# Interpretation of a black hole as an implosion in slow motion

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation

On Isaac Arthur's channel, he mentioned in one of his videos an interesting interpretation of Hawking radiation. Since the Black hole is going to evaporate eventually and all the matter contained within it converted to energy, we can think of it as an implosion. Normally, an implosion would be a quick, violent event. However, the warping of space-time makes it play out in super-slow motion. This would explain why smaller black holes vanish much faster. They don't have enough mass to slow time down as much. Is this a valid interpretation? How come it's not as popular as the one involving "evaporation"?

Comment: putting aside if it has physical significance or not, it is undoubtedly a highly aesthetical interpretation

Comment: Two requests for clarification: (1) What exactly do you mean by *implosion*? Sure, black holes form by implosion. How is that in conflict with evaporation? (2) Why do you say that smaller black holes don't slow time down as much? Do you mean that time slows down just as much, but only in a smaller region?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly - I think he means that the diameter of the event horizon shrinks to nothing during evaporation

Comment: Do you have a link to the channel?

Comment: @mmesser314 Ah, okay. Then I'll modify my request for clarification: When the question says *implode*, does that mean the object shrinks to zero size without losing any mass, as opposed to shrinking because it's losing mass (evaporating)?

Comment: @mmesser314- here is a link to the channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZFipeZtQM5CKUjx6grh54g. Don't have the exact video where he said that, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly - shrinks to zero size while losing mass and converting to energy. For a small enough black hole, this process does happen very quickly and looks very much like an implosion.

Comment: @RohitPandey If implosion just means shrinking to zero size while losing mass and converting to (radiated) energy, then that's a broad enough definition to be consistent with the standard picture of evaporation. Are you asking how the concepts differ? Or are you just asking why people don't use the word "implosion" even though it's broad enough to apply?

Comment: Yes, its the latter. This makes so much more sense and is more elegant that the "evaporation" interpretation. So, why isn't it used more broadly. Also, nice to know its broad enough to apply. Also, does it implies that matter when pushed together enough, annihilates just like matter and anti-matter.

Comment: @mmesser314 "*the diameter of the event horizon shrinks to nothing during evaporation*" - Isn't the radius of the event horizon always zero, defined as the spacelike radial distance to the origin? Once you are at the horizon, your radial interval to the origin is timelike meaning you are already there space-wise, there is no radial direction in space, so you just wait for the singularity to happen. I think a more meaningful statement would be that the circumference of the horizon shrinks to nothing since the circumference is spacelike and non-zero despite the zero spacelike radius. No?