# When pressed together enough, matter annihilates with matter?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

My question is a follow-up to this one: [Interpretation of a black hole as an implosion in slow motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661458/interpretation-of-a-black-hole-as-an-implosion-in-slow-motion). It seems it is perfectly reasonable to think of a black holes as an implosion happening in slow motion. Putting this together with how black holes form - basically matter crunching together, the logical conclusion is that when matter is pressed against itself tight enough, it simply annihilates and dissolves into radiation. Quite like matter and anti-matter. Is this a popular idea? Any quantum mechanical explanation for this?

Comment: to produce radiation from particle collisions various charge conservation laws must be taken into account first. For example colliding electrons cannot produce only photons because total electric charge would not be conserved. Anyway, matter "dissolving" into radiation is not how black holes form. Radiation can itself collapse into black holes in principle

Comment: @Kosm - do you disagree with the assertion in the linked question? The final outcome of a black hole is indeed matter dissolving into radiation. The only question is, how long it takes.

Comment: The radiation in question is Hawking radiation as I assume. To claim that matter dissolves into radiation is misleading because it may give an impression that this radiation is sitting inside the core of the black hole waiting to escape as Hawking radiation. We don't know what is happening inside, while Hawking radiation is a quantum mechanical effect (happening at the event horizon) and not a direct product of collisions of matter particles

Comment: Yes, it is Hawking radiation. And I don't see why the interpretation that it annihilates is wrong. The radiation doesn't "wait" inside, in fact for small black holes the implosion happens very rapidly. The only difference is that bigger ones warp time, making the process last way longer. This is actually the core of my question. Why is the interpretation that this is simply matter annihilating in slow motion "wrong"?

Comment: as I said, Hawking radiation originates at the horizon. While the particles that collapse into a BH are in its "singularity" (unless we are talking about fuzzball scenario). Annihilation meanwhile is a process where two particles collide (strictly speaking one of them antiparticle, but it's not the point) and produce radiation. This process is described by quantum field theory in a certain way, and Hawking radiation is not described this way. Far from it

Comment: Once the blackhole completely evaporates, all the matter that ever fell into it is gone. What happened to that matter? It converted to radiation. Hawking radiation at the horizon is a valid interpretation of this process. However, it isn't the only possible one. Just like the Unrh effect, which is closely related to Hawking radiation has multiple interpretations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cj6oiFDEXc. All you did was say "X is not Y" without describing what is wrong with X. We're on the same page with respect to Y.

Comment: I exactly said why annihilation is not the correct description, it is a simple fact following from how processes are described in QFT. You can use any word you like, but the common rigorous definitions are already there

Comment: But it is matter converting completely to energy at the end of the day. No arguments there? Also, I don't think you can say definitively that annihilation isn't the correct description since you said yourself, we don't know what really goes on inside. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I think I've found the right articulation - there are only two processes we know of where we start with matter and end with pure radiation. Those two are particle, anti-particle annihilation and black holes. Maybe there is a third I'm not aware of. But if those are the only ones, it suggests to me they might be related somehow.

Comment: Black holes violate conservation of all charges, except the electric charge. So even without the Hawking radiation, any electrically neutral black hole today is matter already converted to gravitational energy.

Comment: @safesphere - thanks a ton! Your comments have already helped a lot. It seems there are other quantum properties akin to electric charge that are lost when matter falls into a black hole (and also cancelled when it annihilates with anti-matter)? If you could add a short answer with any references for further reading, that would be great.

Comment: The electric charge is NOT lost in a black hole, but all other charges are lost. The only information a black hole cannot destroy is energy, angular momentum, and electric charge. Here is the reference you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Let's not call it annihilation, as that term is best reserved for interactions between particles and anti-particles.

In short, at high energy scales (like at the center of a black hole) we do not have a complete understanding of physics. "Pressing matter against itself tight enough" means reaching high energy scales and small length scales (think Planck energy and Planck length). At these scales, it may even be possible for baryon number conservation to be broken, which is necessary for turning two protons into photons.

There is no established explanation, but GUT, supersymmetry, and string theory (which I know asymptotically nothing about) offer possible explanations for physics at these higher energies.

Comment: Why is annihilation best reserved for particles and anti-particles if two particles collide and produce the exact same effect (all their matter converted to energy)?

Comment: This is not a physics reason but just a semantic reason. Currently, when people refer to annihilation, it is between a particle and anti-particle. So it's best to avoid confusion by not calling a different exotic situation the same word.

Comment: Got it. My thinking is that there might indeed be some similarity between the two types of "annihilations". If this were established somehow, it would make sense to call them by the same name then.

Comment: @RohitPandey Don't give up your intuition. Annihilation means canceling charges (quantum numbers). A black hole cancels all of them, except for the electric charge. So yes, effectively a black hole annihilates matter even without the Hawking radiation. And, as we observe from outside, this happens at the horizon, not inside, so no high energy physics is involved. This answer is misleading.